# Routing in specific div element with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

I try to display components in specific div but it doesn't work:

Index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./redux/store/index";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from "./Routes";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Routes/>
    </Provider>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Routes.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from "./components/App/App";
import General from "./components/General/General";
import history  from './history';

const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={App}/>
                <Route path="/GeneralPage" component={General}/>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default Routes;
```

In the App component I redirect to GeneralComponent.
In General I want to display differnet components in the div with id content by the nevigate.

General.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { connect, Provider } from "react-redux";
import UpBar from "../UpBar/UpBar";
import Navigate from "../Navigate/Navigate";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import './General.css'
import BooksManagement from "../Management/Books/BooksManagement";
import { Router, Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthorsManagement from "../Management/Authors/AuthorsManagement";

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return ({ users: state.users,
             currentUser: state.currentUser });
};

const GeneralPageConnected = (props: any) => {
 return (
     <div>
    <Grid container>
     <Grid item xs={12}>
        <UpBar></UpBar>
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={12}>
         <Grid container>
         <Grid item xs={10}>
             <div className="content-div" id="content">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/Books" component={BooksManagement}></Route>
                    <Route exact path="/Authors" component={AuthorsManagement}></Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
         </Grid>
         <Grid item xs={2}>
             <div className='navigate'>
                <Navigate></Navigate>
            </div>
         </Grid>
         </Grid>
      </Grid>
     </Grid>
     </div>
 );
}

const GeneralPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(GeneralPageConnected);
export default GeneralPage;
```

Navigate.tsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";
import './Navigate.css';
import history from '../../history';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigate = () => {
    return (
        <div className="compNavigate">
            <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
                <Grid item>
                    <Link to="/Books">ניהול ספרים</Link>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                <Link to="/Authors">ניהול סופרים</Link>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item>
                    ניהול משתמשים
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navigate;
```

It always display a white page without error in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in the navigate.tsx :

```
<Link to="/GeneralPage/Authors">ניהול סופרים</Link>
<Link to="/GeneralPage/Books">ניהול ספרים</Link>
```

or you can just remove the slash

```
<Link to="Authors">ניהול סופרים</Link>
<Link to="Books">ניהול ספרים</Link>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works now!!!
I changed the path in Navigate.tsx and General.tsx to "/GeneralPage/Authors" and "/GeneralPage/Books".